# How to parse MySQL config file my.cnf using parse_ini_file()

Tags: php

When using `parse_ini_file('/etc/mysql/my.cnf')` , the following error message is returned:

```
Warning: syntax error, unexpected '!' in /etc/mysql/my.cnf on line 141
```

This happens because of the last line of the config file, which is:

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Is it possible to use `parse_ini_file()` in order to parse the MySQL config file and bypass the error related to the exclamation mark or should I look into preg_match() instead?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately parse_ini_file will not do the thing. 
You should escape the invalid characters like

> ^!{}~

before parsing it in parse_ini_string
You can consult the manual on the link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-string.php

The following code will do the trick

```
$myfile = file_get_contents("my.cnf");
$invalid = array("!","{","}","~","^");
$myfile = str_replace($invalid, "", $myfile);
$cfg = parse_ini_string($myfile,TRUE);
var_dump($cfg);
```